# Where to find icon for an iOS app, in order to drag it around on the Home Screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen

Let's start out with the idea that I have a rarely-used app that I deinstalled and reinstalled on my iPhone.

In this case, it's a TV remote control app, Remotie in fact.

After redownloading it, iOS has put its icon *somewhere*.  No idea where, really.  I can use `Search`, enter its name and launch it.

But that's tedious and I want to bring it back to my first home screen.

Now, if the icon was on the 2 or 3rd page, I'd press down on it, wait till iOS puts the home screen in edit mode and then drag it leftwards to the first screen.

But how do I do that if I have no idea where iOS has put the icon?  If it was on the Task bar or something like that, I could drag from there.  But that doesn't apply to an iPhone.

Comment: btw should we have a `home-screen` tag or something like it?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the item from the App Library?

Comment: In addition to what @Allan said, there's a group of apps in the App library titled "Recently Added" which you could use to find apps you've downloaded recently. From here, you could hold and press the app you just downloaded and add it to your home screen

Comment: Just did some research, you could go to `Settings`>`Home Screen` and change the `Newly Downloaded Apps` setting from "Add Library Only" to "Add to Home Screen". Now all new apps you download will appear on the home screen by default

Comment: I thought of the App Library (the rightmost home screen) but I couldn't find it there at first.  I eventually did, after asking this question, under a Utilities nested folder.  I think the Search results is easier to work with - esp for people with lots and lots of apps, which is not me.  But I would also upvote an answer on the basis of the App Library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Search for the app
- On the search result screen, press and drag the icon of the app (same way as you would do to move an app on the Homescreen)
- Icon becomes moveable and can be placed on any screen you like.

Comment: Wow, obvious in hindsight, but I never thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your `Home Screen` settings has set ***Newly Downloaded Apps*** to add to *"App Library Only"*, which will mean you won't be able to see your recently downloaded app on any of your home screens unless you search for it or manually find it in the App Library screen (by swiping right to the end of all your home screen pages).

Your solutions are:

- Search for the app and hold down on the app icon to edit your home screen and drag the app to whichever home screen you like.
- Manually find the app in App Library under the *"Recently Added"* category, and hold down on the app icon to edit your home screen and drag it to wherever you want it on your home screen.
- Finally, you can change the `Home Screen` settings for ***Newly Downloaded Apps*** from *"App Library Only"* to *"Add to Home Screen"*. This will change your default settings so that any future App downloads will automatically pop up on your home screen. I think they default to showing on Home Screen page 2 (to avoid cluttering your first Home Screen page). If there's no space on your Home Screen page 2, it will download and appear on page 3, and so on.

See image below with highlighted setting you need to change to show apps by default on your home screen after downloading from the App Store.

[image]

The last solution was the default way of apps downloading and displaying on your home screen, before it got changed with the addition of App Libraries in iOS14.

Hope this helps.